# Angular PrimeNG p-dialog showEffect attribute not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, primeng, bootstrap-dialog

I have problem with my p-dialog. I want to have fade header in my dialog like in this example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/koh9Y.png

But i got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEyvY.png

As you can see my header doesnt have fade effect.
This my html code:

```
<p-dialog header="{{'TASKS.DETAILS' | translate}}" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" [modal]="true"  showEffect="fade">

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row" [ngStyle]="{'width': '500px'}" >
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>{{'TASKS.DESCRIPTION' | translate}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">

            <textarea disabled placeholder=" {{'TASKS.DESCRIPTION' | translate}}"
                      rows="3" cols="30"
            ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >{{'COMMON.CANCEL' | translate}}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        >{{'TASKS.DONE' | translate}}
        </button>
    </div>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including `primeng.min.css` and `theme.css` files in `angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
],
```